# Jquery Spinner doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, browser, spinner

I have implemented Jquery spinner but it works fine on Firefox but doesnt work on Chrome.
i have created two functions called start spinner and stopSpinner
Here is my code

```
function startSpinner(){
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('spinner should be getting shown now');
$('#spinner').show();
});
}


function stopSpinner(){
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('spinner should be getting shown now');
$('#spinner').hide();
});
}
```

**Css Class**

```
.spinner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* half width of the spinner gif */
    margin-top: -50px; /* half height of the spinner gif */
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1234;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100px; /* width of the spinner gif */
    height: 102px; /*hight of the spinner gif +2px to fix IE8 issue */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner">
<img id="img-spinner" src="images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

So whenever i want to call, i use to say 
startSpinner();
and StopSpinner();

Thanks

Comment: " it works fine on Chrome but doesnt work on Chrome"? ;)

Comment: Just edited - works on firefox but not in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
$(document).ready();
```

in both those functions?
From the jquery documentation ( http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ) - "Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded."
So I don't see the reason for using it twice, I think something like this would be better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#spinner').show();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
    hideSpinner();
});

function showSpinner() {
    console.log('spinner should be visible');
    $('#spinner').show();
}

function hideSpinner() {
    console.log('spinner should disappear');
    $('#spinner').hide();
}
```

I used the click event to remove the spinner, but it could be any event (example: ajax has finished loading, img is loaded, login process is complete or anything else). The Dom ready just means "do something as soon as the dom tree is ready".

Comment: i managed to display spinner in chrome it works fine but it does't spin (looks like static image)..

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready is not required here I don't think?

Here is how I would do it:

```
function startSpinner (){
    $('#spinner').show();
}

function stopSpinner (){
    $('#spinner').hide();
}



$(function(){
    $('#on').click(startSpinner);
    $('#off').click(stopSpinner);
});
```

assuming you add two new buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="on" value="on" />
<input type="button" id="off" value ="off" />
```

here is a jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkxKA/

The `$(function() {`.. part is to execute that function when the document loads  - which i think is what you were intending with `$(document).ready`.  here i am using it to register event handlers with the click event.

Let me know if this is not making sense to you  ;)

EDIT:  It seems you have the jQuery part working now and there are still issues with the gif not animating in Chrome

I think maybe this might be to do with chrome being strict about how you display it : 
https://superuser.com/questions/118656/are-animated-gifs-supported-in-google-chrome

in the above link they talk about somethings to check including a repeat setting.

or maybe just a bug in the version of chrome? - probably worth asking a new question to get help from someone else who knows about that specific issue.

Comment: i managed to display spinner in chrome it works fine but it does't spin (looks like static image)

Comment: are you using an animated gif?

Comment: can you upload the giff somewhere and update the jsfiddle i created or just put a link to the gif in the comments

Comment: also what version of chrome are you using it seems like tere may have been some issues with gifs:http://www.ar15.com/forums/t_1_3/1408779_Animated_GIFs_not_working_in_Chrome.html

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/118656/are-animated-gifs-supported-in-google-chrome - maybe the gif is not set to repeat.. in any case maybe mark this answered and then post a new question.. with a link to the gif